# Colour inverted for tiffs in Windows 10 File Explorer preview (but not when you open the image up)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, tiff

When I make jpg files into tiffs the preview of the image shows the colours inverted. I read somewhere that it might have something to do with the 'PhotometricInterpretation' tag being set to a value other than 1. I have no idea what that means or how to change it. I'm using Photoshop CS6 on Windows 10

Interestingly, if I change the colour split to RGB it previews fine. A CMYK jpg also previews fine. So it's not the file format or the colour mode specifically but some sort of interplay with the CMYK colour mode and the tiff file format.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109143/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-james-smith-colour-inverted-for-tiffs-in-window).

Comment: Do you have a high-color monitor (10-bit 12 bit HDR10+ etc)?

Comment: I don't think it's the monitor as tiffs display fine if RGB (as does a CMYK jpg) and I've tried it on a newer version of the monitor with the same result. Can't find the spec for it but it's a View Sonic VX2703